# Convert Phone-gap app to run into Google Glass

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a phone-gap application which I need to convert it so that it can run into my Google Glass.
Do you think its possible to do so, if yes please advice me where to go or how can I achieve it.

Comment: I also want to run my phonegap app in google glass but not getting any idea.. have u solved your issue? If yes then please share the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @NehaAgarwal not yet, i am still doing research on it